# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM + Chromelogger (how to increase HTTP header length limit?)

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, fastcgi, http-headers, mod-proxy-fcgi

I have a running Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM setup.

There is one edge case though, when this setup fails - when using Chromelogger. 
Chromelogger is a server to client debugging tool, which sends it's data through a HTTP header to a browser.
The header's value is usually very long, which causes the mod_proxy_fcgi to fail with a following error:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10452:tid 1912] [client 127.0.0.1:61175] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10452:tid 1912] [client 127.0.0.1:61175] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
```

I tried increasing Apache's LimitRequestFieldSize, but it has no effect on this issue.

My setup in short is as follows:

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

...

<Files ~ "\.(php|phtml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9072#"
</Files>
```

php.ini

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

**On a side note:** The issue does NOT occur, when PHP is running as a module, but it occurs when PHP is running as non-FPM FastCGI.

The header causing the error is returned on GET requests. "X-ChromeLogger-Data" has a value with length of 18716 characters. The value itself is a base64 encoded json object.

I could not find any variable in either mod_proxy or mod_proxy_fcgi that would increase the header limit.
What am I missing? Is there another Apache variable that would help in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe that the http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size is different for the module and the fpm?

Comment: Dear Aleksandar,
The issue occurs on GET requests.
Thank you

Comment: how big are the headers and the request in general?

Comment: Dear Aleksandar,
It is one header with name of "X-ChromeLogger-Data"
and value with length of 18716 characters.
The value itself is a base64 encoded json object.

Comment: what's with the "#" at the end of the Sethandler directive?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but without it - it wouldn't work: 400 Proxy Error: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9072 "URI cannot be parsed"

Comment: @mgo switch it to a trailing slash "/" just in case.

Comment: Dear ezra,
Thank you. / also fixes Proxy Error.
Any ideas to the header length limit?
It is interesting that there is no solution ;-)